# Source control strategy for specific folders within CMS-generated site

Tags: asp.net, version-control, tfs, content-management-system

I have an ASP.NET website where most of the pages are generated and published via a CMS system. This includes static HTML, CSS, ASPX, ASP, images, etc.

However, we have some user controls and pages that are managed by a separate dev team. These files live under the same web root but are not managed in the CMS. These files are limited to a few files and folders under the web root:

```
/bin
/user-controls
/custom-aspx
/web.config
```

(everything else under "/" is CMS-generated)

We don't want to check in all the CMS-generated items into source control (TFS in our case), because those files are constantly changing and versioning is managed within the CMS.

How should we handle source control for the directories listed above? Should we just check those in separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 options:

1. Checkout your version controlled file tree to root and add an ignore parameter for all CMS generated files (assuming they have a set of extensions that make this feasible).
2. Checkout each of the directories (/bin, /user-control, ...) separately to sub-directories of root, and make sure that no CMS generated files are written to these directories.
3. Checkout your version controlled file tree to root and just don't run svn add on any of the CMS generated media.